# PDFLaTeX produces black boxes after executing Sweave

Tags: texmaker, r, sweave

There is the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

    hey there

    <<>>=
    1+1
    @
\end{document}
```

I saved the `example.Rnw` in my home directory an then I executed the `.Rnw` with Sweave("/home/myname/example.Rnw") in R using the terminal.

The output is:

```
Writing to file example.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on ‘example.tex’
```

When I open the generated tex-file with the Texmaker, it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

    hey there

    <<>>=
    1+1
    @
\end{document}
```

I think, at this point the tex-file has to be look different!

When I run PDFLaTeX on the file. The results are little black boxes. << and >> are the black boxes following by the statement `= 1+1 @`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not indent code chunks -- Sweave does not allow that. You can use [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr) instead (run `library(knitr); knit('yourfile.Rnw')` instead of `Sweave('yourfile.Rnw')`).

Comment: Ok it works, this way. Thank you! I just followed the Sweave documentary and usually it has to work. I don't know what's wrong. May be something with my system configurations. The `knitr` package looks good so far. Thanks for the proposal.
With `R` I can connect to my `PostgreSQL` database. Can I do this with `knitr` as well?

Comment: @user15459 You can do whatever you can as long as it works in R since `knitr` is an R package.